# php - phpinfo() is not changed after changing php.ini

Tags: php

When i change content of "php.ini" file that placed in "Configuration File (php.ini) Path" in phpinfo() ,file had been changed but phpinfo() shows unchanged settings.
I'm using Elastix on centOS. This is caused after I install phpmyadmin and after that seseeions did not saved and I wanted to change session.savepath.

Comment: Have you reloaded apache?  Apache uses a cached version of php.ini that is generated when the service starts.

Answer (score 0):

don't forget to restart your service

for example for Apache

> /etc/init.d/apache2 restart